# Plot a Single XGBoost Decision Tree

Tags: python, matplotlib, xgboost

I am using method on https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/ to plot a XGBoost Decision Tree

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# load data
dataset = loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")
# split data into X and y
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]
# fit model no training data
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
# plot single tree
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

As I got 150 features,the plot looks quite small for all split points,how to draw a clear one or save in local place or any other ways/ideas could clearly show this ‘tree’ is quite appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and the only way I found is by trying diffent figure size (it can still be bluery with  big figure. For exemple, to plot the 4th tree, use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
xgb.plot_tree(model, num_trees=4, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

To save it, you can do

```
plt.savefig("temp.pdf")
```

Also, each tree seperates two classes so you have as many tree as class.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Serk's answer, you can also resize the figure before displaying it:

```
# ...
plot_tree(model)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

I found [this workaround](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1725#issuecomment-295059572) on github, which also gives better images with the drawback that you have to open the .png file after.

```
xgb.plot_tree(bst, num_trees=2)
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(150, 100)
fig.savefig('tree.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the to_graphviz method instead - for me it results in a much more clear picture.

```
xgb.to_graphviz(xg_reg, num_trees=0, rankdir='LR')
```

However, most likely you will have issues with the size of that output.

In this case follow this:
[How can I specify the figsize of a graphviz representation of a decision tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346827/how-can-i-specify-the-figsize-of-a-graphviz-representation-of-decision-tree)

Comment: It's the same thing. [`xgb.plot_tree()` is simply a very thin wrapper to `xgb.to_graphviz()`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/plotting.py#L210)

Comment: And it may be slow to show on Jupyter Notebook since svg is hard to handle.