# Plotting tree with XGBoost returns Graphviz error

Tags: python, graphviz, xgboost

I've tried to plot decision tree from XGBoost using 
[Plot a Single XGBoost Decision Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323595/plot-a-single-xgboost-decision-tree). and https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/.
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.load_model("./models/acute_inflammations.model")
#res = model.predict_proba(X_test.iloc[0:1])
xgb.plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

Model was saved with `save_model` method and is working otherwise (I've tried predicting with it). The only problem is with `plot_tree` function, which returns the following error:

```
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jakub/Desktop/thesis_ML/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    xgb.plot_tree(model)
  File "C:\Users\jakub\anaconda3\envs\Inz_ML\lib\site-packages\xgboost\plotting.py", line 248, in plot_tree
    s.write(g.pipe(format='png'))
  File "C:\Users\jakub\anaconda3\envs\Inz_ML\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 136, in pipe
    out = backend.pipe(self._engine, format, data,
  File "C:\Users\jakub\anaconda3\envs\Inz_ML\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 244, in pipe
    out, _ = run(cmd, input=data, capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=quiet)
  File "C:\Users\jakub\anaconda3\envs\Inz_ML\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 183, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd,
graphviz.backend.CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tpng']' returned non-zero exit status 1. [stderr: b'Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:\r\n']

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have Graphviz installed both in Windows ("Stable 2.44 Windows install packages" from the Downloads page) and in Python (`pip install graphviz`). Graphviz is in my PATH system variable. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Can I even fix this, or is it something in XGBoost internals changed with recent Graphviz update (they've updated recently)?

Comment: you can't use the version of 2.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have met the same problem, but I have solved it. How I solved it?
This is my answer.

1. please install the graphviz of 2.3.8.msi。 graphvizz[graphviz](https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/msbuild/Release/Win32/)
2. install what you have download the msi package and then add your install path to the environmenttal path like this 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38; C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'
3. pip install graphviz.
4. the following is my result.
   [image: my xgboost result]

Comment: Thank you! So it’s as I suspected, Graphviz has introduced a bug during update.